# Why does Java give this output?

Tags: java

When trying to run the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num_amount = 7;
    int[] num_array = {3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 12, 1};
    System.out.println(num_array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_array.length; i++) {
        num_array[i] = 0;
        System.out.println(num_array);
    }
}
```

This is the output i get:

```
7
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
[I@ea30797
```

Has anyone ever experienced this "unusual" result? If so, what solution did you try out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, everybody has experience this. It is the default 'toString' of a java array.

Comment: `System.out.println(num_array);` -> `System.out.println(num_array[i]);`

Comment: You are printing the array's reference (which is always the same because it's always the same array). You are changing the values in the array, not the array itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the contents of an array you can use `Arrays.toString`.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you do not print an array by placing the array name inside `System.out.println();`.

Here, you should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num_array));`

See here for how to print an array in Java: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/18449247` (you should use .toString here)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> System.out.println(num_array[i]);

If you want to print each element in new line..

Comment: No, it's obvious from the code that the OP wanted to print the _entire_ array each time through the loop and see it changing one element at a time.